# Grid Bootstrap container keeps overflowing to the right and I can't figure out why

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a margin on the left and on the right of the grid container so it doesn't touch the borders of the webpage - but even though the margin on the left shows up just fine, the margin on the right not only doesn't show up but the container overflows to the right!!

I need the container to be centralized in the middle of the page, its contents still in the ´fluid´ grid mode and spaces in the left and in the right separating the container from the page.

```css
.container-fluid {
  margin: 1vw 2vw;
  padding: 0;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h2>XPTO Album</h2>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ml-12">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x250" height="250px" class="card-img-top object-fit-cover" alt="ufmg">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8 mr-12">
      <h5>Description</h5>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere omnis suscipit, sequi illo eveniet facilis. Cum numquam, veniam labore, et officiis, recusandae delectus modi illum fugit perferendis rerum! Ipsum, earum.</p>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <h5>Location</h5>
            <p>Avenida Presidente Antônio Carlos, 6627 - Pampulha, Belo Horizonte - MG, 31270-010</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-4">
            <h5>Register Date</h5>
            <p>09/24/2023</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. It's difficult to help not knowing. Also see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Frame challenge: Are you _sure_ you need the container to be narrower than the page? The row/column arrangement already creates space at the sides. What is it about your layout that requires this? If so, you just need a more specific CSS selector and you'd also need to reduce the 100% with with a CSS calculation using Bootstrap's custom property values. You can see what's happening with your browser's document inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the container-fluid inside another div and apply the spacing as padding to the wrapper.

```
<div style="padding: 1vw 2vw">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- stuff -->
   </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h2>XPTO Album</h2>

<div style="padding: 1vw 2vw">
  <div class="container-fluid bg-warning">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ml-12">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x250" height="250px" class="card-img-top object-fit-cover" alt="ufmg">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8 mr-12">
        <h5>Description</h5>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere omnis suscipit, sequi illo eveniet facilis. Cum numquam, veniam labore, et officiis, recusandae delectus modi illum fugit perferendis rerum! Ipsum, earum.</p>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
              <h5>Location</h5>
              <p>Avenida Presidente Antônio Carlos, 6627 - Pampulha, Belo Horizonte - MG, 31270-010</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-4">
              <h5>Register Date</h5>
              <p>09/24/2023</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```